# How can one find a system of SDE's from a probability density function?

Tags: distributions, stochastic-processes, differential-equations, stochastic-calculus

Suppose I have a joint distribution function say $p(x,y,z)=f_{X, Y, Z}(x,y,z)$. Is it possible to find a system of stochastic differential equations or a single stochastic differential equation from this?

I know that a Gaussian distribution can be taken as a solution of a heat equation. I have been thinking about a Kolmogorov Equations but I am not sure how to go about it. Your assistance is highly appreciated.

Comment: Gaussian is heat/diffusion equation

Comment: Hello boss @seanv507, I need an assistance fast. I know that boss. I just want a method of getting a system of differential equations whose solution is a stochastic differential equation.

Comment: see the Higher dimensions section. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fokker%E2%80%93Planck_equation

Comment: you wrote wave equation which is different from heat equation

Comment: @seanv507, I have corrected